# a death row inmate's feelings and thoughts

Tags: characters

Any thoughts on what a death row inmate feels or what his thoughts are? i find it hard to imagine it on my own:(

Thanks a lot:)

Comment: i just rephrased the question to make it clear i am not asking about what to write or how to rephrase a passage. also, i have already got two very good answers:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three protagonists will have thoughts and emotions that reveal something about their character. Bonus points if the reader also learns something about their identity within the team. Since they are separated, it's an opportunity to play out the *same* scene with each character and get different results. This can be during interrogation, sentencing, and incarceration – each progressing through stages of how their characters deal with conflict, especially as they switch tactics.

A more plot-oriented approach might be a Try-Fail cycle, where each fails to negotiate their escape (bribe, fight, fake a heart attack). Assuming they eventually reunite and survive death row, the 3 flawed attempts can be echoed in their escape, but this time we see how the team works better together.

A psychologically-inspired approach could use the **[Kübler-Ross model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%BCbler-Ross_model)**, known as **the five stages of grief**. The model describes a progression of emotional states experienced by terminally ill patients. The five stages are chronologically: **denial**, **anger**, **bargaining**, **depression** and **acceptance**.

Answer (score 0):

No one can tell you what to write as each author conjures up worlds unique to their imagination.

You know your characters well by now, so should know how they might respond to such extreme stress.

Consider what they are losing. Before capture, they had hope of success and belief that they would survive. Languishing in a cell, they have failed; the cause is lost, their families and friends are in greater peril and who might rise to take up the fight?

It depends on who they are. Would one write a farewell to his wife that will never be read by her? Might another rail against the injustice of it all? Perhaps one quietly works on an escape that they know won’t happen. Might another carve his name in the wall as a sign that he had once lived?

So many possibilities.

Comment: thank u. this was very helpful. i had considered the three different characters' thought s and feelings based on who they are (a rich palyboy, depressed because he is losing his perfect life, a freedom fighter who ponders the fact that he did not achieved his life-long goal, and a religious woman praying and thinking about her husband) but this was getting repetitive. with your permission, i am going to use your carve the name on the wall and the letter to the love ones. thanks again. this added the variety i needed.